# Can I develop SSIS 2005 in BIDS 2008? the way we can select target framework in VS 2010

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, business-intelligence, bids

I have a BIDS 2008 on my machine, My production is SSIS 2005.

Currently gettting BIDS 2005 is a bit difficulty.

Can I use BIDS 2008 as BIDS 2005?

I have seen couple of such instance in Microsoft technology. In Visual Studio 2010 we can target an older framework. Even IE 8 we could make it work as IE 7 so I thought this might be possible for BIDS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is no :-(

http://geekswithblogs.net/juang/archive/2007/12/12/visual-studio-2008-will-not-support-sql-server-2005-reporting.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The link in the answer by kzhen refers to SSRS not SSIS, but it's the same for SSIS as well, see here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522577(v=sql.100).aspx

> Design packages in Business Intelligence Development Studio. You have
>   to use the SQL Server 2008 version of Business Intelligence
>   Development Studio to develop and maintain packages that are based on
>   SQL Server 2008 Integration Services. Likewise, you have to use the
>   SQL Server 2005 version of Business Intelligence Development Studio to
>   develop and maintain packages that are based on SQL Server 2005
>   Integration Services. You can load and run packages that were
>   developed in SQL Server 2005 Integration Services in the SQL Server
>   2008 version of Business Intelligence Development Studio. However, if
>   you save your changes, the packages are saved in the package format
>   that SQL Server 2008 Integration Services uses. Once saved in the
>   format that SQL Server 2008 Integration Services uses, packages can no
>   longer be opened in the SQL Server 2005 version of Business
>   Intelligence Development Studio, nor run by the SQL Server 2005
>   Integration Services tools.